# Несколько Django приложений на одном сервере

Tags: python, django, nginx

Как настроить nginx для нескольких отдельных Django проектов (разные пользователи, url, функционал) на одном сервере (ip).
Я использую виртуальную машину DigitalOcean.

мой первый nginx file (рабочий для одного проекта)

```
upstream my1app_app_server {
  server unix:/my_1folder_to_socket/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name my_id #like 127.1.1.1;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /my_1folder_to_nginx_log/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /my_1folder_to_nginx_log/nginx-error.log;
    location /static/ {
        alias   /my_1folder_to_stitic/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias   /my_1folder_to_media/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://my1app_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /my_1folder_to_stitic/static/;
    }
}
```

мой второй nginx file

```
upstream my2app_app_server {
  server unix:/my_2folder_to_socket/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name my_id #like 127.1.1.1;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /my_2folder_to_nginx_log/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /my_2folder_to_nginx_log/nginx-error.log;
    location /static/ {
        alias   /my_2folder_to_stitic/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias   /my_2folder_to_media/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://my2app_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /my_2folder_to_stitic/static/;
    }
}
```

Как мне объеденить эти два файла в один, что бы они работали и в результате можно было отправлять запросы на

> http://my_id/my1app/

> http://my_id/my2app/

Я пытался сделать как указано [тут](https://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/). Однако это не поможет мне, поскольку последную инструкцию я не могу выполнить (по другим побстоятельствам)

Comment: Вы нашли решение в итоге?